# How to define a toaster(notifier) plugin globally in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use  [Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) plugin in my application. I want to use it in every module of my application. I want to define it globally so that I can reach from everywhere. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe), and inject into a global controller:

```
app.factory('toastrFactory', function(){
    return {
        error: function(msg){
            return toastr.error(msg[1], msg[0]);
        },
        success: function(msg){
            return toastr.success(msg[1], msg[0]);
        }
    };
});
```

`toastrFactory` in your controller:

```
app.controller('GlobalController', ['$scope', 'toastrFactory',
    function ($scope, toastrFactory) {

}]);
```

Now your controller can call the following when needed:

```
toastrFactory.error(['Error!', 'Record not updated']);
toastrFactory.success(['Success!', 'Record updated'])
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but also note that you can consolidate the toastr settings in this factory as well. Right before the `return` statement place code to set the toastr options: `toastr.options = {/*options here*/};`